# No loader for type: Model?

Tags: java, libgdx

So I converted a model to `.g3db` and got it working fine. But after some very basic refactoring of the code `LibGDX` complains that there is `no loader for type: Model`.

Working code:

```
public GameScene(AssetManager assetManager) {
    this.assetManager = assetManager;
    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    initEnvironment();
    initCamera();

    // Here I load the image with the passed assetmanager
    loadAssets();
}

private void loadAssets() {
    // Following line works
    assetManager.load("data/cube.g3db", Model.class);
    assetManager.finishLoading();

    Model ship = assetManager.get("data/cube.g3db");
    ModelInstance shipInstance = new ModelInstance(ship);
    instances.add(shipInstance);
}
```

Afaik I'm doing exactly the same in the following code and I'm clueless why it fails.

```
public DynamicScene(AssetManager assetManager) {
    this.assetManager = assetManager;

    modelBatch = new ModelBatch();
    initEnvironment();
    initCamera();

    ball = new Ball(assetManager);
}

// Ball constructor
public Ball(AssetManager assetManager) {
    this.assetManager = assetManager;
    loadModel();
}

private void loadModel() {
    // Following line fails
    assetManager.load("data/ball.g3dp", Model.class);
    // Also fails when loading the same model as working example:
    assetManager.load("data/cube.g3dp", Model.class);

    assetManager.finishLoading();

    Model ball = assetManager.get("data/ball.g3db");
    ballModel = new ModelInstance(ball);

    ballModel.transform.setToTranslation(0, 10, 0);
}
```

Both initial classes get passed a `new AssetManager()` to their constructor from the main class.

```
@Override
public void create () {
    //gameScene = new GameScene(new AssetManager());
    dynamicScene = new DynamicScene(new AssetManager());
}
```

Switching back to the working version always runs successfully, running the bottom version always fails.

Comment: Try 'g3db' instead of 'g3dp'.

Comment: Looks like the error message is misleading.